# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API: Car model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm started learning ASP.NET Core, and I am trying to create a web api. I have a demo `Car` class that I want, in Javascript this is how my `Car` object looks like:

```
{
    make: 'AUDI',
    model: 'A3',
    price: 150,
    rentalType: 'day',
    specs: {
        transmission: 'Automatic',
        fuelType: 'Petrol',
        numOfSeats: 5
    },
    imgSrc: 'https://m.atcdn.co.uk/vms/media/0f40778ee8f8402c8cc51fe08eaf2dfd.jpg',
    info: "The Audi A3 is a subcompact executive/small family car (C-segment) manufactured and marketed by the German automaker Audi AG since September 1996, currently in its fourth generation.The first two generations of the Audi A3 were based on the Volkswagen Group A platform, while the third and fourth generations use the Volkswagen Group MQB platform.",
    highlights: {
        "2.0L": 'Turbo 2000CC',
        HORSEPOWER: 200,
        "TOP SPEED": '220 Kmh',
        Gears: 7
    }
},
```

How should the ASP.NET Core model look like? I'm using ASP.NET 6.0 Core Web API. Thanks

Comment: [This converter](https://json2csharp.com/) will do that for you. You don't need to ask us to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems?

Comment: Hi, @devlincarnate, I didnt knew about this website..
I've tried something I though that work, which do worked, but not properly

Comment: Then update your question (or ask a new one if the problem is different) and provide a [minimal,reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you mean when you say it's not working properly. We can't help if we don't have the details of the problem.

Comment: Also, a big part of learning is learning how to [research your questions yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Posting on Stackoverflow should be the very last resort, after you have exhausted all avenues of research. What you are attempting to do is not at all a unique thing and there are tons of existing tutorials, articles, and questions with answers on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Models**

```
public class Highlights
{
        [JsonPropertyName("2.0L")]
        public string _20L { get; set; }
        public int HORSEPOWER { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TOP SPEED")]
        public string TOPSPEED { get; set; }
        public int Gears { get; set; }
}

public class Specs
{
        public string transmission { get; set; }
        public string fuelType { get; set; }
        public int numOfSeats { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
        public string make { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public string rentalType { get; set; }
        public Specs specs { get; set; }
        public string imgSrc { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
        public Highlights highlights { get; set; }
}
```

API:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Car()
{
    Root root = new Root()
            {
                make = "AUDI",
                model = "A3",
                price = 150,
                rentalType = "day",
                specs = new Specs()
                {
                    transmission = "Automatic",
                    fuelType = "Petrol",
                    numOfSeats = 5
                },
                imgSrc = "https://m.atcdn.co.uk/vms/media/0f40778ee8f8402c8cc51fe08eaf2dfd.jpg",
                info = "The Audi A3 is a subcompact executive/small family car (C-segment) manufactured and marketed by the German automaker Audi AG since September 1996, currently in its fourth generation.The first two generations of the Audi A3 were based on the Volkswagen Group A platform, while the third and fourth generations use the Volkswagen Group MQB platform.",
                highlights = new Highlights()
                {
                    _20L = "Turbo 2000CC",
                    HORSEPOWER = 200,
                    TOPSPEED = "220 Kmh",
                    Gears = 7
                }
            };

    return Ok(root);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, First thanks for answer,
but what if the "2.0L" is dynamic and sometimes can be "3.0" or something else.. there is a way to handle it ?

Comment: @Niv -research how to handle a dynamic json key with whatever process you're attempting to do. If you're attempting to create a c# model, then it shouldn't matter what the property name is -- call it something more general than "2.0L". If you're attempting to parse json data into a c# class object, research how to do that when you have a dynamic json key.